# I defined a function to get comments of any specific question from Quora, but it only gets some of the comments. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```py
def GetQuoraComments(html):
    from urllib.request import urlopen 
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
    html = urlopen(html)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    search=bs.find_all('span')
    comments=[]
    for item in search:
        bsp=BeautifulSoup(str(item), 'html.parser')
        comment_parts=bsp.find_all('p',{'class','ui_qtext_para u-ltr u-text- 
        align--start'})
        if len(comment_parts)>0: 
            comments += ['\n'.join(['\t'+x.get_text() for x in 
            comment_parts])]
    print(len(comments),' comments fetched.')
    return comments
```

Let's say I passed "https://www.quora.com/16-Pizzas-are-ordered-for-the-children-at-a-party-Each-pizza-is-cut-into-8-equal-slices-Each-child-eats-2-slices-There-are-4-slices-left-How-many-children-are-at-the-party" in my function. I'm supposed to get 100+ comments, but I'm only getting like around 8.

Comment: select code and use button `{}` to correctly format it.

Comment: open web browser, turn off JavaScript and load page on Quora - and you will see the problem. Page uses JavaScript to add comments. BS/urllib will not run JavaScript. You may need Selenium to control web browser which will load page and run JavaScript